# Wrong button sizes while using wpf xceed toolkit wizard

Tags: c#, wpf, wizard, toolkit, xceed

I'm using the wizard from the wpf xceed toolkit. The problem is that the buttons are not the same sizes. All examples I can find show the buttons the same sizes. When I use it, the Cancel and Finish buttons are larger, and the Cancel button is clipped on the left side. Has anyone else experienced this, and do you have solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to set the padding for the button.

Comment: Buttons look just fine for me. Post your XAML.

Comment: Post some of your sample code here. I will help.

Comment: I did a test but couldn't reproduce the issue you are having. Perhaps there is something in your XAML or theme that is affecting the button sizes. If you still need help, you can send us an email at support@xceed.com